# plt.plot in python, annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can i get a random number between -0.1 and 0.1 to stand next to the data in the plot? This is what I've tried so far, but it is not working...

```
grades = np.array([[-3,3,7],
                   [7,0,12],
                   [2,4,4],
                   [7,12,10]])

tasks = np.arange(1,grades.shape[1]+1)
n = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,len(grades))

plt.figure()
for i in range(len(grades)):
    plt.plot(tasks,grades[i,:],'b.')

    for i, txt in enumerate(n):
        plt.annotate(txt, (tasks[i],grades[i,:]))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grades = np.array([[-3,3,7],
                   [7,0,12],
                   [2,4,4],
                   [7,12,10]])

tasks = np.arange(1,grades.shape[1]+1)
n = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,len(grades))

for i in range(len(grades)):
    plt.plot(tasks,grades[i,:],'g^')
    for j, txt in enumerate(n):
        plt.annotate(txt, (tasks[j-1],grades[i-1,j-1]))
plt.show()


#Edit:
#Can u try this For unique labelling: 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
grades = np.array([[-3,3,7],
                   [7,0,12],
                   [2,4,4],
                   [7,12,10]])

tasks = np.arange(1,grades.shape[1]+1)
n = np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,len(grades))
tmp_list = []
for i in range(len(grades)):
    plt.plot(tasks,grades[i,:],'g^')
    for j, txt in enumerate(n):        
        if (tasks[j-1],grades[i-1,j-1]) not in tmp_list:
            plt.annotate(txt, (tasks[j-1],grades[i-1,j-1]))
        tmp_list.append((tasks[j-1],grades[i-1,j-1]),)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It works! But the only thing is that because of the loop I get only 3 different random numbers, and I would like to have an individual number next to each grade in the plot so that when two grades overlap you'll be able to see it because of the random number next to it. Any suggestions to how I could do that? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can u check the edited answer, if it suits ur use case